# Wrong start date in irregular intervals chart

Tags: highcharts

Start date in irregular series is not same with date which is shown on mouse-over tip.
Also, you can check this on HC demo page for Winter serie start date: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time

[image]

How can I fix this, so both date point to regular one.

TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error. XAxis labels is calculated for only to fit the screen. There may be no point on label. For this example, time is fragmented per-14-days. If time is too long, may be fragmented more than 14, OR less than 14.

> XAxis labels not represent points. It only shows timeInterval.